# Printing the custom testcase name in the report using testng

Tags: webdriver, testng

I am using data provider to pass parameters in testng and want to print custom testcase name (it will be based on the type of data I am passing to the testcase). How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

[Parameters in Dataproviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) looks like what you want.

> If you declare your @DataProvider as taking a java.lang.reflect.Method
>   as first parameter, TestNG will pass the current test method for this
>   first parameter.

That bit of documentation also provides an example.